# How to inverse hover a hotspotted image?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a hotspotted image as follows:

```
<div class="hotspotted">
    <img height="100%" width="100%" src="puzzle_hotspot.png"/>
    <a href="a.html" id="hotspot1" class="hotspot"></a>
    <a href="b.html" id="hotspot2" class="hotspot"></a>
</div>
```

I would like that when I hover over hotspot1 the rest of the page darkens. How do I achieve that?

I thought something along those lines (but those lines do nothing):

```
.hotspot {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.hotspotted:hover a{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.hotspotted a:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you actually looking for it to "darken" or are you looking for it to become "transparent" (which is more what your attempted code appears to be trying to do)? Also, do you only want this function for `hotspot1` or (as your code appears to be) for each `hotspot`?

Comment: question edited. I want the function for each hotspot. I guess that by getting one to work I will be able to get the other too.

Comment: Does the word `function` imply you are going to use JavaScript or jQuery or is this a Pure CSS solution that your looking for?

Comment: @arttronics: So far, it looks like CSS only. "I want the function for each hotspot" should probably be "I want it to function for each hotspot".

Comment: @simpatico, **+1** for the term `CSS Function`, I just had to [**Google**](http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=130) it. I think a method to consider is to use a `div` with `id="hotspotOverlay"` and use CSS `before:` or CSS `after:` that would effect this overlay when `hotspot1` has a `:hover` event. So far, my attempts are not working. Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqYrh/)

Comment: Well isn't that ironic!? That Googled link in my previous message is doing what you need as seen while hovering the **Suburban Glory Logo**. Doing so will dim the page but not that element, and it's doing it in CSS. The CSS rules (and functions) are in the [**style.css**](http://www.suburban-glory.com/styles/style.css) file for the `hover` tag. CSS3 is used, but for other header tasks. I'll study what rules are needed for the work-in-progress jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS3 Solution

It is apparent that you want to control the `opacity` levels of the elements rather than an "overlay" of them. That was a little tricky, but there is a solution I found for CSS3 capable browsers (tested in IE9, FF, Chrome). Use the following (as demonstrated in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R7t6C/14/); of course, `opacity` levels can be changed to what you want):

```css
.hotspotted > img,
.hotspotted > img ~ a {
    opacity: 0.2; /* "default" opacity of "page" when hovering a hotspot */
}

.hotspotted:not(:hover) > img,
.hotspotted:not(:hover) > a,
.hotspotted > img:hover,
.hotspotted > img:hover ~ a,
.hotspotted > img ~ a:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* normal display opacity and that of hovered hotspot */
}
```

### Explanation

The first two selectors with `opacity: 0.2` are set to make it a sort of "default" opacity for all elements inside `.hotspotted`. Then, this default is overridden by the next five factors. The first two...

```css
.hotspotted:not(:hover) > img,
.hotspotted:not(:hover) > a
```

... make sure that when you are not mousing over the web page that everything is solid. The next two...

```css
.hotspotted > img:hover,
.hotspotted > img:hover ~ a
```

... make sure that when you do mouseover into the web page, but *not* over a hotspot, that everything still stays solid. Then the last one...

```css
.hotspotted > img ~ a:hover
```

... keeps the hotspot solid on a hover of it, but then allows the "default" from the first two "takeover" and fade all the other elements in the `.hotspotted` container.

Comment: In your fiddle your img essentially acts as a background for the whole page. Things don't work the same for me: http://jsfiddle.net/R7t6C/16/

Comment: @simpatico--your image also acts as a page background. It isn't working because you are trying to change _part_ of the image by another element's hover. That is not possible in css. You need to either: 1) break your image into two images that are each contained in the `a` tags and "rebuild" the image on the screen (this could be done as `background-image` instead of `img`), or 2) use an [`imagemap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) mapped via Dreamweaver or some [online tool](http://www.image-maps.com/) and then set highlighting for that. #2 allows fine tuning around your puzzle shapes.

Comment: none of those are options. The imagemap is not because of the fluid layout (and that percentages in imagemaps didn't work on the iPad).

Comment: @simpatico--Okay, I grant the `imagemap` cannot be made fluid. However, splitting your image into two (or three, the hand as "background" and the two puzzle pieces in the `a` tags) would seem (from my view) a perfectly plausible solution for your needs (of course, I do not know all your goals). The fact is, it is basically the _only_ way you are going to get what you want for effect.